# how to validate if element's value is not empty in Katalon Studio

Tags: katalon-studio

Im doing automatic test of my web page with usage of Katalon Studio. My problem is that I dont know how to validate if HTML element has none-empty value ex. "", "  ".

Is there any quick tip for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to verify that a html-element has a specific value, you can use:

```
WebUI.verifyEqual(yourElement.getAttribute('value'),'')
```

Finding the element:

```
def driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()

WebElement elem = driver.findElement(ByTagName.tagName('theElementYouWantToFind'))
```

So if you want the test case to fail in case of empty value:

```
WebUI.verifyNotEqual(yourElement.getAttribute('value'),'')
```

Comment: I meant to check if it contains none-empty value, so if empty then stop test. Your expression works for empty string.

Comment: it seems to be not exact answer and exact syntax...how to find object?:)

Comment: Full example added?

Answer (score 2):

My solution is following:

```
value = WebUI.getAttribute(findTestObject('Object/Repository/input_aaa'), 'value')
if (value == '') { throw new Exception('Empty value found')}
```